# What is the best method to create subdomain in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, subdomain, multiple-users

I am currently developing a site written in primarily Codeigniter that allows users to signup and enter in some information. I would like to give them a unique url (web page) on my site that contains their information so it can be favorited, or quickly accessed by them. Do I need to create a folder in the virtual directory for each user ? Also I would like to give them some themes to select from to use for their custom homepage.

Comment: You can reference this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3873554/is-there-an-easy-way-to-create-subdomains-on-codeigniter

Comment: Well,I googled and found out that instead of creating subdomains,cretae subfolders in the name of users and use htaccess to redirect to user.domain.com when accessed domain.com/user .I want to know which method is better when I also want to use theming inside???